# How do I await an async method in F#

Tags: f#, async-await

How do I await an async method in F#?

**I have the following code:**

```
 type LegoExample() = 

    let brick = Brick(BluetoothCommunication("COM3"))
    let! result = brick.ConnectAsync();
```

**Error:**

> Unexpected binder keyword in member definition

Note, I reviewed the following [link](http://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/concurrency-async-and-parallel/):

However, I only observe the functional technique and not the OOP technique.

Comment: btw: what I don't understand the last part - are you talking about the class `LegoExample`?

Comment: Yes. I'm trying to do this using F#'s OOP support.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

you get the error because the `let!` construct (just like the `do!`) needs to be placed inside a *computational workflow* (like `async { ...}` but there are others - it's basically the syntactic sugar F# gives you for monads - in C# it would be the `from ... select ...` stuff LINQ came with and in Haskell it would be `do ...` blocks)

so assuming `brick.ConnectAsync()` will return indeed some `Async<...>` then you can *wait* for it using `Async.RunSynchronously` like this:

```
let brick = Brick(BluetoothCommunication("COM3"))
let result = brick.ConnectAsync() |> RunSynchronously
```

sadly a quick browser search on the page you linked did not find `ConnectAsync` so I cannot tell you exactly what the indent of the snippet was here but most likely you wanted to have this inside a `async { ... }`  block like this:

```
let myAsyncComputation =
    async {
        let brick = Brick(BluetoothCommunication "COM3")
        let! result = brick.ConnectAsync()
        // do something with result ...
    }
```

(note that I remove some unnecessary parentheses etc.)

and then you could use this `myAsyncComputation`

- inside yet another `async { .. }` workflow
- with `Async.RunSynchronously` to run and await it
- with `Async.Start` to run it in background (your block needs to have type `Async<unit>` for this
- with `Async.StartAsTask` to start and get a `Task<...>` out of it
- ...

Comment: Hi Carsten, do I have to create a separate function "myAsyncComputation"? I would like to have this done within my type LegoExample. However the Async { } throws a build error when I embed it inside my LegoExample type.

Comment: it does not have to be a function but if you want to call it in the constructor (almost everything you write with `let` and `do` before the first `member` will be in the classes constructor` then you probably want to use the very first thing I gave you and ignore the async aspect - if you want you can think about `Async` just as `Task` and the `async { ...}` stuff is what you would do with `async` and `await` in C# (only better :P)

Comment: Thanks Carsten. The build errors are resolved. The ConnectAsync operation succeeds. Now I just need to figure out why the execution of my motor and sound are not being observed.