# Get entity details when StorageException is thrown

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, azure-table-storage

When operating on tables and blobs and something goes wrong, Azure throws a `StorageException`. `.RequestInformation.ExtendedErrorInformation` will give you a bit of information about what went wrong, such as this when trying to insert a duplicate key into a table:

`The specified entity already exists`

Is there any way to get information about which entity caused the exception?

Comment: The `Request​Result.​Extended​Error​Information` property is of type `StorageExtendedErrorInformation` which contains an `IDictionary <string, string>` called `Additional​Details`. Any chance that dictionary contains the duplicate entity/Id?

Comment: @AndrésNava-.NET no, it's actually empty!

Comment: If you use program to do that, please have a try to use fiddler to catch the detail error info.

Comment: @TomSun-MSFT I was hoping to get information on the entity programmatically, so it could be included in error logs

Comment: According to response info from table service, I also can't get which entity already exists. If TableOperation.InsertOrMerge(ITableEntity) is acceptable, we could use it to avoid conflict. We also could give our [feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/217298-storage) to Azure Storage team

Comment: @TomSun-MSFT Yes, I actually switched to InsertOrMerge already, but it would be nice to get the entity details in the case of any other exception that may be thrown

Comment: If we have any ideas, we could give our [feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/217298-storage) to azure team

Comment: @TomSun-MSFT done! https://feedback.azure.com/forums/217298-storage/suggestions/19737901-storageexception-should-include-information-on-rel

Answer (score 0):

Currently, if we execute bulk insert, it seems that there is no way to get which detail entity casues the exception.

If we have any ideas, we could give our feedback to Azure team that as you have done.

I also mentioned that we could use the **TableOperation.InsertOrMerge(ITableEntity)** to avoid conflict.

Another work around is that if insert one by one entity is acceptable, then we could use variable to log the current insert entity info. If there is exception, then we could log the detail info by ourselves. The following is snippet demo code:

```
var customEnity = new CustomEntity();
try
{
   foreach (var entity in list)
   {
       TableOperation insertOperation = TableOperation.Insert(entity);

        customEnity = entity;

       // Execute the insert operation.
       table.Execute(insertOperation);        
   }

 }
 catch (Exception)
 {

    //Do something
 }
```

Comment: I realise that I could structure my code differently to determine which entity failed, but it would still be useful - even for a *single* entity, not just bulk inserts - if the exception contained some info about the entity that failed

Comment: I agree with you. But If a `single` entity then we could get the entity info easily .

Comment: Not necessarily easily if you're using async

Comment: Based on my experice, we could using `await` to do that. Anyway, if we could get detail info from azure storage service side, it will be wonderful.

Comment: In my particular case I'm using F# to process a list of asynchronously; at least if you're an F# noob, it's not as obvious as with C#.

Comment: I found another [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35522447/how-do-i-await-an-async-method-in-f-oop) it is related to F#  await and async.But I am not familiar with F#. Hope it is useful.